# Javassist version upgrade does not solve java.lang.VerifyError:

Tags: java, java-8, jboss, java-7, javassist

We have an old project compiled with 1.7 and we want to change its runtime env to 1.8
(still will be compiled with 1.7).
After changing runtime env to 1.8, we got a lot of `java.lang.VerifyError` in logs.
For exp one of them:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfsfile:/opt/mss/mss-1.5.0.FINAL-jboss-jdk6-5.1.0.GA/XXX/ state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfszip:/opt/mss/mss-1.5.0.FINAL-jboss-jdk6-5.1.0.GA/XXX/
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:274)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:263)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 14
Exception Details:
  Location:
    classpath/ClassName.$javassist_read_YYY()Lcom/classpath/ClassName; @10: ifnonnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0010 2ab9 04df 0100 c700 04b0 4c2a
    0x0000010: b904 df01 002a 1305 462b b904 e604 00c0
    0x0000020: 0548 b0                                

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotatedClassFilter.hasAnnotations(AnnotatedClassFilter.java:194)
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotatedClassFilter.accepts(AnnotatedClassFilter.java:122)
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotatedClassFilter.visit(AnnotatedClassFilter.java:102)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.vfs.helpers.WrappingVirtualFileHandlerVisitor.visit(WrappingVirtualFileHandlerVisitor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:362)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:374)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:374)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:374)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:374)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:374)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:307)
    at org.jboss.virtual.VFS.visit(VFS.java:468)
    at org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:448)
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.getClasses(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:225)
    at org.jboss.deployment.ConvergedSipAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processSipMetaData(ConvergedSipAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:103)
    at org.jboss.deployment.ConvergedSipAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(ConvergedSipAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:90)
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    ... 30 more
```

At first I used `-noverify`, which solved the problem.
However I realized that using `-noverify` for production application is not a good idea.
As far as my investigation, it is suggested to upgrade `javassist` version. And since in stacktrace Javassist is mentioned (`classpath/ClassName.$javassist_read_YYY()Lcom/classpath/ClassName; @10: ifnonnull`) I decided to give it a try.

I almost tried with every Javassist version including 3.19 (build with jdk8)
and it does not work. Still verify error.

What is the solution for this? Or is there a workaround for this issue?

System info: JBoss 5.1.0.GA and Maven 2.2.1

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Javassist might be a red herring here. The method name `$javassist_read_YYY` contains “Javassist” and looks like a typical generated method name, but that doesn’t prove that this method was injected at runtime nor that it was generated with Javassist. Only when these two points are true, the version of the Javassist library at runtime has an influence. It’s strange that the affected class has the qualified name `classpath.ClassName`, but a return type with the qualified name `com.classpath.ClassName`. And neither name seems to be part of an official library.

Comment: Thank you very much @Holger for the answer. As far as I understand, you are saying that javassist might not be the source of the problem, right? And very sorry for misleading you about classpath, className part but I was actually trying to mask package and class names there, since it is a company project. The original location was something like this: com/genxx/waxxx/model/entities/XXXServiceImpl.$javassist_read_password()Ljava/lang/String; (@)10: ifnonnull. But I can not understand where to check from this information.

Comment: Then, it sounds more like runtime bytecode injection. When you say “every Javassist version including 3.19”, does this include versions above 3.19? Current version is 3.27

Comment: The newest version I tried was 3.24 @Holger, but that did not work as well